# Is it possible to specify a property naming strategy with an annotation?

Tags: rest, jackson

I have a class defined as:

```
class Person {
    public int age;
    public String firstName;
}
```

Note that I use camel case for the field names. Also, I know that I could have generated getters and setters but I tend to not do that for simple domain objects.

When I deserialize a JSON or XML response in my REST API, it should spit out:

```
<Person><Age>11</Age><FirstName>Johnson</FirstName></Person>
```

*You will notice that the first letter is upper-cased.*

I could use, for example, @JsonPoperty("FirstName") on my POJO to get the output the way I need it, but this doesn't scale when there are too many fields. I'd like to use a custom property naming strategy (as described in [How To Use Property Naming Strategy In Jackson](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-use-propertynamingstrategy-in-jackson.html)). But instead of configuring an `ObjectMapper`, I was wondering if its possible to specify a naming strategy using annotations?

Thanks